# Updating Pandas DataFrame Specific Range

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have a Pandas DataFrame whose index is an DateTimeIndex (hourly stepped), the columns are the name of the rooms and each cell is a `set()`.

```
                 room_a   room_b ... room_az
2017-01-01 12:00 {}       {}     ... {}
2017-01-01 13:00 {}       {}     ... {}
2017-01-01 14:00 {}       {}     ... {}
...
2019-12-12 23:00 {}       {}     ... {}
```

I have to put the right persons in the right rooms during the time he/she/they occupied it. The data comes from another DataFrame that is like

```
index person_id room   beg_effective_dt_tm end_effective_dt_tm
1     55        room_a 2017-01-01 15:45:33 2017-01-15 10:33:54
2     55        room_a 2017-01-25 09:15:55 2017-02-15 15:33:42
3     10        room_a 2017-01-05 12:10:33 2017-02-10 09:33:25
4     10        room_b 2017-02-10 09:34:15 2017-03-25 10:14:15
...
15000 55        room_z 2019-05-10 12:15:45 2019-05-10 15:33:25
15001 60        room_x 2019-06-02 15:10:33 2019-08-10 10:33:42
...
n
```

So I tried

```
for _, row in enumerate(df_origin.itertuples(), 1):
    interval_start = hour_rounder(row.beg_effective_dt_tm)
    interval_finish = hour_rounder(row.end_effective_dt_tm)
    df_sets.update(
        df_sets.loc[
            interval_start:interval_finish, row.room
        ].apply(lambda s: s.add(row.person_id))
    )
```

But, for each `row` this code is updating the whole respective column (room), ignoring the time span.
Without `apply` the series are been correctly selected, but the `apply` is setting the whole respective columns.

What am I missing here?
How can I implement this idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the data frame from where the data comes from?

Comment: Just provided, @BrunoMello